# How can a button be de-prioritized so it is 'skipped' as the page's default button?

Tags: asp.net

I have a complex web app with hundreds of controls, dozens of pages and about a dozen masterpages. Using ContentPlaceHolders, different form content is generated within the main body of each page, such as a login prompt on one page and 'add to favorites' button on another.

Common to all of these pages is a search bar. When the search bar is at the top, it captures the enter key every time the enter key is pressed. If I move the search bar below the main content, through some codebehind and javascript, it correctly captures the enter key only when the search field is in focus.

What I'd like to do is leave the search bar at the top of the page, but de-prioritize it so when the enter key is pressed the default button is whatever happens to be second on the page. My aim is to avoid adding javascript to every possible control that could appear in the main body of the page.

**How can a button be de-prioritized so it is 'skipped' as the page's default button?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to take a different tact and simply assign the button you want as the page's default.

Modify the `<form id="aspnetForm" runat="server">` tag to be something like:

`<form id="aspnetForm" runat="server" defaultbutton="NameOfTheButtonYouWant>`

If you want a different default depending on where the users cursor is then wrap the relevant areas in a `<asp:panel>` which also has a defaultbutton attribute.

---

**Update from the comment.**

The only other idea I have might be difficult to implement.  The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/constraints.html#implicit-submission) says that the

> first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form
>   element

is the default.

So, if you can move the search area such that it is at the bottom of the HTML file, but still renders at the top, then you *might* be successful.  However, this is going to require some tinkering with layouts to make it work.

Comment: Hmm, there's no fixed button ID that could be assigned to the form in all cases, so that't won't work. As for setting individual panel defaults, this is a bit unweildy due to the number of pages that would have to be touched. Is there a way to automatically set the default button based on content within a content placeholder? Something like: "set the default for panel 'foo' based on the first button ID in content placeholder 'bar'"?

Comment: I can confirm this last approach works, so it's the best option out of the lot. I was hoping there was a way to 'ignore' the first button, but looks like it's not possible. Thanks!